# Вызов функций c++ из qml

Tags: c++, qt5, qml

Подскажите что делаю не так. Написал простую функцию которую хочу вызвать в qml.

Header:

```
class BackEnd : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  void shutDown();

signals:
private:
};
```

cpp:

```
BackEnd::BackEnd(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{
}

void BackEnd::shutDown()
{
  string syscol = "shutdown /s /t 0";
  system(syscol.c_str());
}
```

В main зарегистрировал тип

qmlRegisterType("io.backend", 1, 0, "BackEnd");

Внутри файла qml я могу вызвать BackEnd но функцию shotDown не могу, что не так в написанном коде ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы было видно данную функцию необходимо добавить `Q_INVOKABLE` перед декларацией функции в заголовке:

```
class BackEnd : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT


public:
  explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  Q_INVOKABLE void shutDown();

signals:
private:
};
```

Ну и для полной красоты стоит изменить свой main :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
qmlRegisterType<BackEnd>("io.backend", 1, 0, "BackEnd");
BackEnd backEnd;
QQmlContext* cntx = engine.rootContext();
cntx->setContextProperty("backEnd", &backEnd);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Надо чтоб она попала в moc файл:

```
class BackEnd : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void shutDown();
...
}
```

** UPD **
Согласен с товарищем ixSci, если метод как слот не нужен, лучше Q_INVOKABLE написать

Comment: Не нужно делать слотом то, что им не является. Для этого есть `Q_INVOKABLE`.